# VerifyIDToken on Go SDK got panicked

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I've no idea why the VerifyIDToken on Go SDK got panicked. I've used VerifyIDToken on the handler of gin as follows:

```golang
    r.GET("/idToken/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
        //      idToken := c.Param("id")
        opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("xxx-secret.json")
        app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("error initializing app: %v", err))
        }

        client, err := app.Auth(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error getting Auth client: %v\n", err)
            fmt.Println(client)
        }

        idToken := c.Param("id")
        fmt.Println("idTaken = ", idToken)

        token, err := client.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idToken)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error verifying ID token: %v\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Verified ID token: %v\n", token)
    })
```

I've called above API as follows:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {

        user.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
          // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
          // ...
          axios
          .get('https://xx.xxx.com/idToken/' + idToken)
          .then(response => {
            this.response = response;
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.update == "ok") {
              this.acceptOKresponse = true;
            }
          })
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle error
        });
```

Then, Followings appeared on the server console:

```
idTaken =  eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlYTNmN2EwMjQ4YmU0ZTBkZjAyYWVlZWIyMGIxZDJlMmI3ZjI0NzQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.ABnMA6iOITghzo_WzgdDwssODiLsswVSlKod6w5CHcnkJOQVKqQIynZufTQvcF8nQO77MYXikZD8TQE_uGq3EpHWQibun67mvN74GnPaguzgvpjQ-PqIOzuhnn2n2SpHSacdREtFkwtj1S66bhigbuTJbqr8jQtIEIB6gfmnObwcmpNRsc-GGR45xjWAO6UY4Ygw4xDcHsHGXwL6SA-HbDuSZGeQfXtdPt94taJfrQQB9nr_7gRjttQLz4ongh-g-fMSpWx3z8lmQgPwgg4GyChYPZ6_hdEV3AWFJTHptE2X8RCV6HfpZB6EGwvLQr6ZrC01uodGTg87BvtPrersjA


2020/03/02 13:35:58 [Recovery] 2020/03/02 - 13:35:58 panic recovered:
GET /idToken/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlYTNmN2EwMjQ4YmU0ZTBkZjAyYWVlZWIyMGIxZDJlMmI3ZjI0NzQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.ABnMA6iOITghzo_WzgdDwssODiLsswVSlKod6w5CHcnkJOQVKqQIynZufTQvcF8nQO77MYXikZD8TQE_uGq3EpHWQibun67mvN74GnPaguzgvpjQ-PqIOzuhnn2n2SpHSacdREtFkwtj1S66bhigbuTJbqr8jQtIEIB6gfmnObwcmpNRsc-GGR45xjWAO6UY4Ygw4xDcHsHGXwL6SA-HbDuSZGeQfXtdPt94taJfrQQB9nr_7gRjttQLz4ongh-g-fMSpWx3z8lmQgPwgg4GyChYPZ6_hdEV3AWFJTHptE2X8RCV6HfpZB6EGwvLQr6ZrC01uodGTg87BvtPrersjA HTTP/1.1
Host: ml.uedasoft.com
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ja,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Connection: Keep-Alive
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
X-Forwarded-For: 125.172.88.148
X-Forwarded-Host: ml.uedasoft.com
X-Forwarded-Server: ml.uedasoft.com


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:199 (0x5595f)
    panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:394 (0x55838)
    sigpanic: panicmem()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_arm.go:103 (0x126db)
    goXadd64: *(*int)(nil) = 0 // crash on unaligned uint64
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/trace/trace.go:483 (0x50b937)
    (*defaultIDGenerator).NewSpanID: id = atomic.AddUint64(&gen.nextSpanID, gen.spanIDInc)
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/trace/trace.go:196 (0x50a26f)
    startSpanInternal: span.spanContext.SpanID = cfg.IDGenerator.NewSpanID()
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/trace/trace.go:162 (0x50a117)
    StartSpan: span := startSpanInternal(name, parent != SpanContext{}, parent, false, opts)
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp/trace.go:58 (0x51713b)
    (*traceTransport).RoundTrip: ctx, span := trace.StartSpan(req.Context(), name,
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp/client_stats.go:54 (0x516b1b)
    statsTransport.RoundTrip: resp, err := t.base.RoundTrip(req)
/home/ueda/.go/src/go.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp/client.go:89 (0x5165c7)
    (*Transport).RoundTrip: return rt.RoundTrip(req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:250 (0x25ec27)
    send: resp, err = rt.RoundTrip(req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:174 (0x25e6ef)
    (*Client).send: resp, didTimeout, err = send(req, c.transport(), deadline)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:641 (0x25fb17)
    (*Client).do: if resp, didTimeout, err = c.send(req, deadline); err != nil {
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:509 (0x4f9def)
    (*Client).Do: return c.do(req)
/home/ueda/.go/src/golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp/ctxhttp.go:30 (0x4f9d60)
    Do: resp, err := client.Do(req.WithContext(ctx))
/home/ueda/.go/src/firebase.google.com/go/auth/token_verifier.go:92 (0x59750b)
    (*httpKeySource).refreshKeys: resp, err := ctxhttp.Do(ctx, k.HTTPClient, req)
/home/ueda/.go/src/firebase.google.com/go/auth/token_verifier.go:72 (0x59733b)
    (*httpKeySource).Keys: err := k.refreshKeys(ctx)
/home/ueda/.go/src/firebase.google.com/go/auth/token_verifier.go:129 (0x5979e3)
    verifyToken: keys, err := ks.Keys(ctx)
/home/ueda/.go/src/firebase.google.com/go/auth/auth.go:223 (0x59529f)
    (*Client).VerifyIDToken: if err := verifyToken(ctx, idToken, c.keySource); err != nil {
/home/ueda/ml/main.go:97 (0x5fdc33)
    main.func5: token, err := client.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idToken)
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x48710f)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/recovery.go:83 (0x497efb)
    RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x48710f)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/logger.go:241 (0x497347)
    LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x48710f)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:412 (0x48f8bf)
    (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/home/ueda/.go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:370 (0x48f19f)
    (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2802 (0x2a2c7f)
    serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1890 (0x29f12f)
    (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:868 (0x6c86f)
    goexit: MOVW    R0, R0  // NOP

[GIN] 2020/03/02 - 13:35:58 | 500 |   13.345389ms |  125.172.88.148 | GET      /idToken/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlYTNmN2EwMjQ4YmU0ZTBkZjAyYWVlZWIyMGIxZDJlMmI3ZjI0NzQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.ABnMA6iOITghzo_WzgdDwssODiLsswVSlKod6w5CHcnkJOQVKqQIynZufTQvcF8nQO77MYXikZD8TQE_uGq3EpHWQibun67mvN74GnPaguzgvpjQ-PqIOzuhnn2n2SpHSacdREtFkwtj1S66bhigbuTJbqr8jQtIEIB6gfmnObwcmpNRsc-GGR45xjWAO6UY4Ygw4xDcHsHGXwL6SA-HbDuSZGeQfXtdPt94taJfrQQB9nr_7gRjttQLz4ongh-g-fMSpWx3z8lmQgPwgg4GyChYPZ6_hdEV3AWFJTHptE2X8RCV6HfpZB6EGwvLQr6ZrC01uodGTg87BvtPrersjA
```

I've completely no idea of the cause of this panic. Any suggestions are so welcome! Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Your handler needs to exit once it encounters an error, or at least it should do something that doesn't require the primary return values to be present. It is bad practice to just print the error and then continue as if nothing happened! `if err != nil { return }`.

Comment: ... fix your code to something like this https://play.golang.org/p/3NaAyb_UJdt and if you still get the same error let us know.

Comment: Thank you mkopriva, I've fixed as you pointed, but the same error is still keeping appear.

Comment: The bug has been reported [here](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go/issues/865) and it should be fixed since [Aug 16, 2018](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go/commit/1789eaf7638d6f16d055afd35654928c04663cfc#diff-c74a48081d4d8360b4a570379a806b79). Try updating your dependencies, mainly the `go.opencensus.io` package. If that doesn't fix it maybe you can try opening a new issue on their github page.

Comment: Thank you mkopriva! It's fixed after go get -u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482703/verifyidtoken-on-go-sdk-got-panicked#comment106999950_60482703) by [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva), root cause was a reported issue. It's fixed by updating dependencies as follows:

```
go get -u all
```

Thank you, mkopriva!